# How to name JAXB classes?

Tags: java, jaxb

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyRoot {
    private List<SubRootDTO> subs;
}

public class SubRootDTO {

}
```

How can I give an explicit JAXB name to the `SubRootDTO` class?

Comment: See the [XmlElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html) annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different options:

1. Annotate `SubRootDto` with `@XmlRootElement` and then use `@XmlElementRef` on all mapped fields/properties that reference it.
2. Annotate the `SubRootDto` properties with `@XmlElement`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "subRoot")
public class SubRootDTO {
}
```

Comment: OK I thought `@XmlRootElement` annotation would only be applied to the most outer class?

Comment: We used it like this, but I might also suggest the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256221/automatic-xmlrootelement-wrapper-for-list: @XmlElement(name = "xmlUsers")

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRootElement
class MyRoot {
    private List<SubRootDTO> subs;

    ...

    @XmlElementRef(name = "CustomName")
    public List<SubRootDTO> getSubs(){
        return subs;
    }
}

class SubRootDTO {

}
```

In contrast to annotate `SubRootDTO` with `@XmlRootElement(name = "XYZ")`, `@XmlElementRef(name = "ABC")` allows you to name the element differently for each reference.